# Cakephp load element with BBcode/shortcode

Tags: cakephp, element, helper, shortcode

I am looking for input/help on how to do this. Might be some PHP/cake developers could provide some good solutions here. Cakephp 2.3 something :)

**Problem;** How to put shortcodes in wysiwyg editor (example: **[slideshow=1]slideshow here[/slideshow]**) and render an element (in this case, loading and displaying the slideshow with ID=1).

ShortcodeHelper.php

```
App::import('Helper', 'Html', 'Router');
class ShortcodeHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $shortcodes = array( 
        'slideshow' => '/(\[slideshow=)(.+?)(\])(.+?)(\[\/slideshow\])/'
    ); 
    public $returncodes = array( 
        //'slideshow' => $this->render('/elements/slideshow', array('id'=>'\\2'))
        'slideshow' => '<strong rel="\\2">\\4</strong>' 
    ); 

    public function render($content, $render=null) {
        $shortcodes = $this->shortcodes;
        $returncodes = $this->returncodes;
        if(isset($render)) {
                $temp_shortcodes = array(); 
                $temp_returncodes = array(); 
                foreach ($render as $key => $value) { 
                    $temp_shortcodes[$key] = $shortcodes[$value]; 
                    $temp_returncodes[$key] = $returncodes[$value]; 
                } 
                $returncodes = $temp_returncodes; 
                $shortcodes = $temp_shortcodes; 

        }
        $return = preg_replace($shortcodes, $returncodes,  $content); 
        return $this->output($return); 
    }
}
```

view.ctp (call render function from helper, and run the page-content trough it):

```
<?php echo $this->Shortcode->render($page['Page']['body']); ?>
```

Thanks. You are awesome!! :)
-Tom

Comment: So I solved it another way. Using helper, I return a <div id=1> and use jquery to check if it exist, if exist, ajax load the element. Simple. Thanks for any input on this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the short code string into a method call, parse it.

Your helper will need to be able to detect them and then break them up. Your code needs to be mapped somehow to a callback.

```
// [slideshow=1]slideshow here[/slideshow]
$this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'slideshows', 'action' => 'view', $id);
```

For example.

I think the best way here would be to just always map the first arg, the "function call" to an element instead and pass all other args to the element. This way you can do there whatever you want and request the data or just simply display HTML only.

I would put the mapping of short codes into something like Configure::write('ShortCodes', $shortCodeArray); this way plugins could even register their callback mapping by simply adding them to that array.

```
array(
    'slideshow' => array('controller' => 'slideshows', 'action' => 'view')
);
```

You'll have to merge that with args from the parsed short code.

Why requestAction()? You should not violate the MVC pattern, for this reason you'll have to request the data via requestAction().

Comment: I did not quite follow your reasoning. The thing is, I have posts with no slideshow, I have maybe, a couple, with slideshows inside. I need to do a check if the shortcode "slideshow" is inside the 'body', and if it is, render the element.  The reason I need to do this, is to allow for non-programmers, to simply insert a slideshow to any post, and it will automatically appear in the view when using the shortcode in the wysiwyg editor (in admin). I am not requesting any data, but "Render slideshow-element.ctp". All data from DB and output, is done in the element using requestaction.

Comment: So simply put, Look trought the $post['Post']['body'] (content of the post). Check if shortcode [slideshow=ID] exist, if shortcode exist, render slideshow-element.ctp for that ID in the exact location shortcode is written in the post. (all data retrieval from DB is done in element using requestaction + output of the retrieved data).